# Responsive design: Do I have to make a media query for each mobile width?

Tags: responsive, media

I am trying to practice responsive design but the problem is I have imgs in a container and they don't scale with the container after each dimension.  How do I get my images to change in size according to the change in mobile device I select in the "inspect element" tool?  Hopefully this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting your img `width: 100%;` and `height: auto;`
that should make the img fit into your container.

Comment: ok, so I added it to the original coding and it is too small.  how do I make it bigger while still getting it to adjust in conjunction with the page mobile screen sizes.

Comment: by changing the dimensions of your container

Comment: Can I just send you my coding?  I can't figure this out.